# Replace text with control markup using Visual Studio macro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, replace

I'm trying to replace some text in an ASPX page with a literal control using a Visual Studio (2010) Macro, but it seems that the control markup is being modified on replacement.

I've got an ASPX page with the following:

```
<span>Foo</span>
```

Which I'm trying to replace with:

```
<span><asp:Literal Text="<%$ Resources:Foo %>" runat="server" /></span>
```

This is being done by highlighting the "Foo" text and then running a macro to replace the text.  However, when executing the macro, Visual Studio is not pasting the text exactly as entered.

My macro code looks like this:

```
Dim Selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
Selection.Text = "<asp:Literal Text=""<%$ Resources:Foo %>"" runat=""Server""/>"
```

However, when the macro executes, it inserts this:

```
<asp:Literal Text=""<%$ Resources:Foo %>" runat="Server" /> %>"
```

Note the first set of double quotes (though the others are correct) and additional `%>"` added at the end.  This seems to occur if the replacement text includes any quotes.  For example, if I just try and replace the selected text with `<asp:Literal runat=Server"/>`, it works properly.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can workaround this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found a solution, though it's more of a workaround.  The strange behavior seems to be caused in part by the 'format code on paste' setting in Visual Studio, which when disabled, fixes the issue with the double quotes but not the extra markup being added at the end.

To get around this, I'm now replacing the text with a random string, and then rewriting the file with the new text.  The downside of this is that Visual Studio throws up a prompt stating that the file has changed and asking whether it should be reloaded, which needs to be done to see the update, but at least the actual file content is now correct.

The code looks like this (simplified for this example):

```
Sub ReplaceText()

    'This is the markup we want to replace our selection with
    Dim LiteralMarkup As String = "<asp:Literal Text=""<%$ Resources:Foo %>"" runat=""Server""/>"

    'Generate random GUID to do initial replace
    Dim RandomGuid As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    'Now replace the selection with the generated guid
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = RandomGuid

    'Save the file
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Save()

    'Now replace the generated guid with the real markup that we want
    Dim NewText As String = File.ReadAllText(DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName).Replace(RandomGuid, LiteralMarkup)

    'Rewrite the file (will cause VS to prompt user to reload file)
    File.WriteAllText(CurrentPath, NewText)

End Sub
```

It's not an ideal solution, but it does the trick.

For anyone who's interested, this code is being used in a macro that is designed to ease the process of moving text from aspx or ascx files into resource files.  The full code is available here: https://gist.github.com/1591239